# How can i display the values in the spinner from the another class?

Tags: java, android, spinner

I want to pass the value from **MainActivity.java** to the **Name.java** and access the values from the **Name.java** and want to display it in the spinner.

How can I do that do this? and also want to Toast the name on selecting the value from the spinner. please help me in this.

Thanks in advance.

**Name.Java**

```
public class Name {

    private String name;

    public Name(){

    }

    public Name(String name) {
        this.name =  name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.Java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<Name> names = new ArrayList<>();
    Name name = new Name();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        names = new ArrayList<>();

        Name name = new Name();
        name.setName("dog");
        name.setName("cat");
        name.setName("cow");

        names.add(name);

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

        spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Name>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, names));

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Name value = (Name) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
              Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "value is "+value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: What is your issue?

Comment: this code doesn't display any values in the spinner..

Comment: My guess is that that's because you used "Name" as the type of value that should be displayed in the spinner instead of String

Comment: Use like this in your Toast message `"value is " + value.getName()`

Comment: But "dog", "cat" ,"cow" this is not showing in the spinner

Answer (score 0):

Override `toString` method inside `Name.java` and return `name`.

```
public class Name {

    ...
    @Override
    public String toString(){ 
      return name;  
    }
}
```

This will help to display the items in the `Spinner`.

You need to add items to the `ArrayList`. Currently you are adding only one item to the `ArrayList`.

```
...
names = new ArrayList<>();

names.add(new Name("dog"));
names.add(new Name("cat"));
names.add(new Name("cow"));

Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
...
```

Comment: where do I call this toString() in mainactivity?

Comment: You don't have to.